# Create And Implement a Custom Form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, custom-controls

I am trying to create a customized form class (CustomBorderlessForm) in VB.NET.

### My Progress So Far

1. I created a new Class and named it CustomBorderlessForm.vb
2. I then proceeded to write the following code:

CustomBorderlessForm.vb

```
    Public Class CustomBorderlessForm

        Inherits Form
        Dim _form As Form = Nothing

        Public Sub New(form As Form)
            _form = form
            MsgBox("Testing: New()")
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
            MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
            MsgBox("Testing OnMouseMove()")
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Form1.vb

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim form As New CustomBorderlessForm(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

### Results of progress

- A message box displays "Testing: New()" on load
- Nothing shows on mouse move

As you can see, my problem lies with the events

### Questions

1. Is it possible to create a form object and use that instead of the pre-populating form?

   - If so, can I give this form custom properties, such as, a border and some boolean values (shadow...etc), just like any other custom object/class?
2. What am I doing wrong in my current approach?

   - Why isn't the OnMouseMove being overridden?
   - Am I initialising the class wrong?
   - Can it even be done this way?

Comment: if you eventually, add custom properties or events, you will have to do it a bit differently.  In that case, you will need to add the base class to a ClassLib so the IDE can work from a compiled version.  So far, it appears mostly cosmetic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a form you also need to show it. Change your logic to:

```
Dim form As New CustomBorderlessForm(Me)
form.Show()
```

Before you do that, I'd recommend changing from `MsgBox` to `Console.WriteLine()`, otherwise you can run into a fun/frustrating little cat and mouse game.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, if, from VS you did a "Add New, Windows Form" you can just right-click the project, select property and on the Application tab change the Startup object to your new form. VS only allows you to do this with forms it creates for you (by default, more on this later).

If you wrote that file by hand (which is absolutely fine) you can perform the `Show()` like I did above and call `Me.Hide()` to hide the "parent" form. Unfortunately the `Load` event is fired before the `Show` event so if you place this in `Form1_Load()` it won't work. Instead you can use the `Shown` event like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim form As New CustomBorderlessForm(Me)
    form.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

Another option has to do with "Application framework". You can [read about it here](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2007/10/01/enable-the-application-framework-in-vb.aspx) however it basically handles application events that other languages have to manually implement. If you go into your project properties you can uncheck the "Enable application framework" checkbox. This will give you more option in the "Startup object" dropdown. If you add the following code to your project one of the items in the Startup object dropdown menu should now be "Loader"

```
Public Module Loader
    <STAThread()>
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim form As New CustomBorderlessForm(Nothing)
        form.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Module
```

You'll notice that the above bypasses `Form1` completely. Also, instead of `Show()` I'm using `ShowDialog()` because otherwise the form shows and then the program ends.

Comment: Ahh...I see. So I'd have to have to close the initial form after this code? If so, I won't be able to add objects in designer mode...

Comment: You can have as many forms as you want showing. Its just that `New` by itself doesn't make a form visible.

Comment: It creates a kind of 'child form' which closes with the parent. I don't want 2 forms on display:(

Comment: I think I get what you're trying to do. Are you using VS? If so, are you letting VS create the form for you or are you trying to do it all by hand?

Comment: I am trying to create a custom form so I can use it just like the default form in designer and handle its events. Yes, I am using VS and if you're asking whether I picked 'Windows Form Application' when creating the project, yes, I did

Comment: I've updated my answer above with some more options for you. If I'm still not on the write track just let me know.